# Attempting to upgrade to latest release from 22.10 and I get this error

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I can see that it looks like the system is unable to reach these packages that don't exist on the source server(s) but ... trying to change to different ones in the Updating Settings GUI doesn't seem to actually change them.

```
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.37-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-13/gcc-13-base_13.1.0-2ubuntu2%7e23.04_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-13/libgcc-s1_13.1.0-2ubuntu2%7e23.04_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl3_3.0.8-1ubuntu1.2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-13/libstdc%2b%2b6_13.1.0-2ubuntu2%7e23.04_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/libw/libwebp/libwebp7_1.2.4-0.1ubuntu0.23.04.2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tiff/libtiff6_4.5.0-5ubuntu1.2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/f/freetype/libfreetype6_2.12.1%2bdfsg-4ubuntu0.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-6_1.8.4-2ubuntu0.3_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-xcb1_1.8.4-2ubuntu0.3_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxpm/libxpm4_3.5.12-1.1ubuntu0.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/libc/libcap2/libcap2_2.66-3ubuntu2.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libssh/libssh-4_0.10.4-2ubuntu0.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ncurses/libncurses6_6.4-2ubuntu0.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ncurses/libncursesw6_6.4-2ubuntu0.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ncurses/libtinfo6_6.4-2ubuntu0.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2_2.9.14%2bdfsg-1.1ubuntu0.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/a/avahi/libavahi-client3_0.8-6ubuntu1.23.04.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/a/avahi/libavahi-common3_0.8-6ubuntu1.23.04.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/a/avahi/libavahi-common-data_0.8-6ubuntu1.23.04.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-13/libgomp1_13.1.0-2ubuntu2%7e23.04_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/speexdsp/libspeexdsp1_1.2.1-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-13/libatomic1_13.1.0-2ubuntu2%7e23.04_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-15/libllvm15_15.0.7-3ubuntu0.23.04.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-12/gcc-12-base_12.3.0-1ubuntu1%7e23.04_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gst-plugins-base1.0/libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0_1.22.1-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcups2_2.4.2-3ubuntu2.5_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/svt-av1/libsvtav1enc1_1.4.1%2bdfsg-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/libv/libva/libva-drm2_2.17.0-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/libv/libva/libva-x11-2_2.17.0-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/libv/libva/libva2_2.17.0-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/ocl-icd/ocl-icd-libopencl1_2.3.1-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavcodec59_5.1.2-3ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libswresample4_5.1.2-3ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/libw/libwebp/libwebpmux3_1.2.4-0.1ubuntu0.23.04.2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/aom/libaom3_3.6.0-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/libg/libgsm/libgsm1_1.0.22-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/librsvg/librsvg2-common_2.54.5%2bdfsg-1ubuntu2.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/librsvg/librsvg2-2_2.54.5%2bdfsg-1ubuntu2.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/libv/libvpx/libvpx7_1.12.0-1ubuntu1.2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/z/zvbi/libzvbi0_0.2.41-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavutil57_5.1.2-3ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4_7.88.1-8ubuntu2.3_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gst-plugins-base1.0/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base_1.22.1-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gst-plugins-good1.0/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good_1.22.1-1ubuntu1.2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gst-plugins-good1.0/libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0_1.22.1-1ubuntu1.2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gst-plugins-base1.0/gstreamer1.0-x_1.22.1-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wine/libwine_8.0%7erepack-4_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wine/wine32_8.0%7erepack-4_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/intel-gmmlib/libigdgmm12_22.3.4%2bds1-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/intel-media-driver/intel-media-va-driver_23.1.2%2bdfsg1-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/restricted/n/nvidia-graphics-drivers-525/libnvidia-compute-525_525.125.06-0ubuntu0.23.04.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mesa/mesa-va-drivers_23.0.4-0ubuntu1%7e23.04.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
Failed to fetch https://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/libv/libva/va-driver-all_2.17.0-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.2.70 443]
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Did you run `apt update` ?

Comment: Yes. Looks okay until the final line:
Reading state information... Done
2325 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

Comment: When I run sudo apt-get upgrade I get a bunch of not found IP errors

Comment: You can't upgrade to the *latest* release (23.10) as Ubuntu 22.10 had only a single upgrade which was to the next release (23.04).  Your process has become harder due to EOL, where after EOL the main archive is moved & mirrors are free to drop support (thus packages won't be found). https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades will be useful